# Problem to prove a point lies on a circle.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

> In $\triangle ABC$ it is given that $\angle ABC=60$.
> Let the perpendicular bisector of $AC$ meet angle bisector of $\angle B$ at $X$.
> Prove that $X$ lies on the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$.

I have tried angle chasing but I am not able to conclude that $\angle XBC$ = $\angle XCB$ = $30$.

Comment: The $60^\circ$ condition is a red herring, you don't need it. Find the midpoint of arc $AC$ not containing $B$. Show that this point lies on both angle bisector and perpendicular bisector. Done.

Comment: Yes, the actual problem was different. I just realised I had incorrectly modified it to this..

Comment: I would recommend drawing and posting a picture of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two versions for you:

[image]

On the left, draw the circumcircle, start by forming the perpendicular bisector on $AC$, shown in gray. Then note that the angles marked by $1$ are the same since they subtend the same chord on the circle. Likewise for $2$. Finally, note that the perpendicular bisector causes $AZX \cong CZX$, so that $1=2$ and $BX$ is an angle bisector.

Or, on the right, start with the angle bisector $BX$, shown in gray. Again by inscribed angles subtending the same chords, we also have angle $1$ in two corners of $\triangle ACX$, implying it is isosceles, and hence if we draw its altitude that it will bisect $AC$ at right angles.